# tkinter and python3.x button config

Tags: python, tkinter, config

I am trying to write a string to text. This is the code:

```
def retrieve_input():
    inputValue = textBox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    c = inputValue

    def open():
        f = open("writetest.txt", "a")

        def write_input():
            f.write(c)

filemenu.add_command(label="Write to txt", command=lambda:retrieve_input())
```

I tried many ways but not success, the whole code is long and really not pretty, I try to learn the command about writing and loading from.

Comment: What does "not success" mean? Is the wrong data being written? Is no data being written? Is the function not being called? Does the program crash? Have you examined the value of `c` inside of the `open` method to verify that it is what you think it should be? Is this all your code for the `retrieve_input` function? You define `open` but aren't calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether your indentation is actually as it is in your post, but here is a cleaner way:

```
def retrieve_input():
    inputValue = textBox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    c = inputValue

    with open("writetest.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(c)
```

I got rid of all the functions which had not really reason to be. In addition, I chose to use a `with` instruction for handling the file.

Besides, your function could be way shorter:

```
def write_input():
    with open("writetest.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write(textBox.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
```

Note that you were opening the file, but not closing it after. This could lead you to memory leaks. Using a `with` block protects you from such things, because it automatically close the file. Also, in your code, `textBox` is not defined, so you need to either pass it as an argument, or declare it as `global` (avoid the latter).